# count unique with multiple criteria, what should i do?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YZLW.png)
I want to count uniquely in multiple criteria but it seems the formula isn't working
The count should be 6 instead of 3.5
what should I do?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1712921/edit) your question and give all the details (criteria, output/result, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `COUNTIFS` function. Adapt the following formula to suit your range:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,D2,B1:B5,E2 & "*")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it will cause another problem that if in column B1 contain C-1, B2 contain C-1 B4 contain C-2 and B4 contain C-2 the formula should just count C-1 and C-2 one time for each so the result should 2 not 4. Do you understand my explanation but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @patcharita Then your criteria is C-1 not C-.